# When page is reloaded from anywhere in application its goes to initial page in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

- In webapp, routing is used.
- Initial page having header details and login page is included using ng-include because login page is separate html page and also it has ng-view tag.
- login page having hyperlink of register when user click on register then login page made explicitly hidden from controller and when registeration submitted its redirected to new page and same with login page also and this has been done with angular routing.
- But, whenever after any page refreshed or reloaded its goes to my initial page i.e. index.html which having login details.
- Now, don't wanted such case whenever page refreshed it suppose to be on same page unless and until there is not any url changes.

### index.html

```
<body ng-app="docpointApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div id="wrap">
        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div ng-include="'/doc-demo/parts/login.html'">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

### login.html

```
<div id="loginUser" ng-controller="appController">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div ng-show="showPage" >
            <form class="form-horizontal" name="loginForm">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="loginUser()">Login</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--- Some login details--->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="">
                            <a href="#/view-register" ng-click="showRegister()">REGISTER}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </form>            
        </div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### view-register.html

```
<div id="registerUser" ng-controller="appController">
    <div class="panel-body" >
        <form class="form-horizontal css-form" name="registerForm">
            <div class="form-group">
             <!-- Some registration details---->
                <div class="">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="registerUser()">register</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Some Other files

```
<!--menubar.html,home.html,createRequest.html,pendingRequest.html etc
-->
```

### docpointapp.js(Javascript file)

```
var docpointApp = angular.module('docpointApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

docpointApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/view-register', {
                    templateUrl: '/doc-demo/parts/view-register.html',
                    controller: 'appController'
                }).
                when('/view-docmain', {
                    templateUrl: '/doc-demo/parts/docmain.html',
                    controller: 'appController'
                }).
                when('/login-user', {
                    templateUrl: '/doc-demo/parts/login.html',
                    controller: 'appController'
                }).
                when('/create_request', {
                    templateUrl: '/doc-demo/parts/createRequest.html',
                    controller: 'appController'
                }).
                when('/pending_upload_requests', {
                    templateUrl: '/doc-demo/parts/pendingRequest.html',
                    controller: 'appController'
                }).
                when('/index', {
                    templateUrl: '/doc-demo/parts/home.html',
                    controller: 'appController'
                }).
                when('/available_request', {
                    templateUrl: '/doc-demo/parts/pendingRequest.html',
                    controller: 'appController'
                }).
                when('/assigned_request', {
                    templateUrl: '/doc-demo/parts/pendingRequest.html',
                    controller: 'appController'
                }).
                when('/processed_request', {
                    templateUrl: '/doc-demo/parts/pendingRequest.html',
                    controller: 'appController'
                }).
                otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
    }]);

docpointApp.factory('loginSvc', [function () {
        var loginProperties = {
            isLoggedIn: false
        };
        return loginProperties;

    }]);
docpointApp.controller('appController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', 'loginSvc', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, loginSvc) {
        $scope.user = {

            'id': '',
            'userName': '',
            'password': '',
            'firstName': '',
            'lastName': '',
            'type': ''
        };

        $scope.logout = function () {
            loginSvc.isLoggedIn = false;
            $scope.isLoggedIn = loginSvc.isLoggedIn;
        };

        $scope.loginUser = function () {
            loginSvc.isLoggedIn = true;
            $scope.isLoggedIn = loginSvc.isLoggedIn;
            var res = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/doc-demo/actions/user-login',
                data: $scope.user
            });
            res.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                loginSvc.isLoggedIn = true;
                $scope.isLoggedIn = loginSvc.isLoggedIn;
                $scope.user = data;
                if ($scope.user.type === "ROLE_PROOF_READER") {
                    $scope.showProofReader = true;
                    $scope.showOfficer = false;
                } else {
                    $scope.showOfficer = true;
                    $scope.showProofReader = false;
                }
                if ($scope.user.loginStatus === "loggedIn") {
                    $scope.showPage = false;
                    $location.path("/index");
                }
            });
            res.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
            });
        };

        $scope.showPage = true;


        $scope.showRegister = function () {
            $scope.showPage = !$scope.showPage;
        };


        $scope.registerUser = function () {
            var res = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/doc-demo/actions/user-register',
                data: $scope.user
            });
            res.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.user = data;
                if ($scope.user.type === "proofreader") {
                    $rootScope.showProofReader = true;
                    $rootScope.showOfficer = false;
                } else {
                    $rootScope.showOfficer = true;
                    $rootScope.showProofReader = false;
                }
                $location.path("/index");// page redirection after register sucess
            });
            res.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
            });
        };
        $scope.search_pending_request = function () {
        //some details
        };  
    }]);
```

Comment: What about your url styling dose it has a #

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: This is how SPAs work.  Single Page Applications don't run by themselves, they run in the page you have loaded.  If you refresh the page, you are restarting the App.  Some routing frameworks allow you to "jump in" to the middle of an application to a unique state, but you'll still need to save some data client side or be able to load the data for that application state from the server.

Comment: @Explore-X yes it has a '#'.

Comment: @Claies: If want to achieve the same thing how can it be?

Comment: well, I would say that the first issue would be that every route is using the same controller (`appController`), and it assigns `$scope.user` to essentially an empty object when it's first instantiated.

Comment: @Claies : does it impact all pages if we using the same controller

Comment: does it impact all pages in what way? I'm not sure what you are asking.  Your initial question is why your page gets reset when you refresh, and I'm suggesting that the controller you are using would definitely cause a reset.

Comment: also, you have `otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});` but you don't have a `/home` route defined....

Comment: @Claies: tried out separating controller and structure but same issue still persisting.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what is happening with your app.  **You cannot stop the application from restarting on page reload.** You can only be prepared for the possibility, and manage your data so that when a user loads a page other than the root, Angular can *start* the app from that point.

Comment: you'll have to show some new code to explain what "separating controller and structure" means, but I suspect that you still haven't solved the issue of the fact that your `user` object is still empty when the app starts, no matter what page you are trying to start from.

Comment: bottom line, based on the code you have posted so far, the application *will not* work the way you want it to, and it's not a simple fix.  It will take studying how the application and browser interact, and re-thinking how the app itself is structured.

Comment: Actually that user object its just for reference while sending to server side, initially its just kept blank value whenever data is field from ui then its assigned to user object in controlller.

Comment: yes, but you rely upon that data on other pages, correct? and when that other page is reloaded, that data doesn't exist anymore, and has to be fetched from the server again, which means you have to log in again.

Comment: yes, most of the pages required that details. so do you have any solution for it?I guess session is good option?

Comment: @Claies: see the ans pasted here, have look on it and I would appreciate your help..

Comment: I can't explain how you would fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for the answer but page refresh can be achieved by using the combination of `$cookies` and `$httpProvider.interceptors.push`. Basically you can capture all the routing in cookies and in all controller you can get the last routing page info from cookie and redirect accordingly using `$localtion`.